# EndpointNotFoundException when calling a service

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I successfully added a service reference to my ASP.NET project, but I get a `EndpointNotFoundException`, when I try to call a method from a service client:

```
BenchmarkManagementServiceClient client = new BenchmarkManagementServiceClient();
try {
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(userId);
    if (client.VerifyUser(id)) { //Here is the exception thrown
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userId, false);
    }
} catch (FormatException) { }
client.Close();
```

Thats curious, because I can access the address of the service via a browser and nearly the same code works in another project (Windows Forms).

Thanks for your help.

Edit:

The message of the inner exception is `The remote name could not be resolved`

The service I try to request is running in the Azure-Cloud.
The ASP.NET project is running locally on my computer.
My other project (where everything works fine) also runs locally on my computer.

Maybe it's good to know, that I had to create the Service Reference without the package `Newtonsoft.Json`. Otherwhise occured warnings during the code generation for the service reference.

Comment: might be a firewall/antivirus problem.

Comment: I don't think so, because it works with my other project. My ASP.NET project is tested locally on the same machine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2288243/1262700 might help you.

Comment: No. Didn't helped me. Why should I need a proxy bypass, when the same service works in another project? I think it has to be something ASP.NET specific.

Comment: You should make this more clear in your question. What is running in Azure? What isn't? Are you running everything locally (in IIS/in the emulator) or are you testing some parts while deployed in Windows Azure?

Comment: have you confirmed what host it's actually trying to reach?  The WinForms and ASP.NET apps will be using different client configs - try tracking the network activity via Fiddler or IE tools to see if the host you think you're contacting is the right one.

Comment: Are you sure this is difference between ASP.Net and WinForms?  It might as well be connected to the user running the calling program, your WinForms will run in your name, while your ASP.Net will typically run as a system user.  Try setting the identity on the application pool to your credentials and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Do you mean the web adress of the service reference? If yes, this address is reachable.

Comment: I can't find the application pools... They should be in the Computer Management under Services and Applications.

Comment: You will need to include more details to get an answer, like your endpoint details from your config file to start with.

Comment: Also, please check if you are going through a proxy - this could mean that your web browser goes through the proxy and resolves the service correctly, but in code you are not using a proxy and perhaps that is why it fails?

Comment: Sorry for your trouble guys. It was a problem with the proxy, as tpaksu and shenku mentioned. I used the wrong post, as I tried to use a proxy bypass for the first time.

Answer (score 3):

I was behind a proxy and had exactly the same issue.

Adding this section to my configuration fixed the Proxy Authentication error for me.

```xml
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
</system.net>
```

Comment: Please consider putting comments into the comments box, instead of answers